# How to remove/delete ContentControl in Canvas WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

i'm starting with WPF and i have a problem. Please help me. Thanks, sorry for my bad English!

I have added ContentControl to a Canvas, and i want to remove/delete it.

Draw ContentControl code:

```
ContentControl cc = new ContentControl();
cc.Content = shape;
cc.Height = h;
cc.Width = w;
Style s = myCanvas.FindResource("DesignerItemStyle") as Style;
cc.Style = s;
Canvas.SetLeft(cc, x);
Canvas.SetTop(cc, y);
myCanvas.Children.Add(cc);
```

I use HitTest to remove it but i can remove only shape

```
 private void myCanvas_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Point pt = e.GetPosition((Canvas)sender);
        HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(myCanvas, pt);            
        if (result != null)
        {
            myCanvas.Children.Remove(result.VisualHit as Shape); //it works with shape  
            // i have changed it into  myCanvas.Children.Remove(result.VisualHit as ContentControl); 
             //but it didn't work with ContentControl           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is so because the `ContentControl` is the parent of the `Shape`, and the `Canvas`'s children contains the `ContentControl` that hosts the shape.
You could do this to fix your issue :)

```
private void myCanvas_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject ob = FindAncestor<ContentControl>((DependencyObject)e.Source);
    if (ob.GetType() == typeof(ContentControl))
            myCanvas.Children.Remove(ob as ContentControl);           

}

public T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

        if (parent == null) return null;

        var parentT = parent as T;
        return parentT ?? FindAncestor<T>(parent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you the next solution:

```
        private void myCanvas_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var dObj = sender as DependencyObject;
        if(dObj == null) return;
        var ob = dObj.GetChildOfType<ContentControl>();
        if (ob != null)
        {
            myCanvas.Children.Remove(ob);
        }
    }
```

Helper code:

```
 public static T GetChildOfType<T>(this DependencyObject depObj)
    where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj == null) return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

            var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

just put the helper inside the public static class as it is an extension method

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can add the control, for example:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle() { Name = "MyName" };
```

and to remove from the canvas:

```
UIElement element = StationLayout.FindName ("MyName") as UIElement;
StationLayout.Children.Remove(element);
```